# Making Dumpling Conserve Better

Tags: storage-method, asian-cuisine, reheating, dumplings

When I make Chinese or Japanese style dumplings I often make too many and then store some for the next day

When I reheat them, they always go a bit strange and seem to taste worse then when they were fresh

Are there ways to store or re-heat the old dumplings to make them conserve better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dumplings should freeze very well.  If you freeze the uncooked dumplings immediately and then cook longer the next day, you should have a similar result to your freshly assembled dumplings.

Comment: Yep; when you freeze them, set them on a plate, not touching, in a single layer until frozen hard, then you can transfer them to a bag. This freezes them faster and prevents sticking.